# Control USB power from Pi

Tags: usb-power, power-management

I would like to control USB LED currently pluged into power socket from my Pi.

I understand that it is not possible to simply switch ON/OFF given USB port on Pi. So is there some way, I could modify the USB cable for example to then switch it ON and OFF via GPIO connection or something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: What type of USB LED? Is this just an LED light or something like the blinkstick with a microcontroller? Control how simply turn off and on via the Pi?

Comment: @SteveRobillard it's this one: http://www.gearbest.com/electronics-gadgets/pp_280338.html Yes just ON/OFF control, not brightness or other stuff

Comment: Any idea what the power requirements of your light are?

Comment: Here http://budgetlightforum.com/node/37323 guy says he measured 0.25A, but I think this is the old version without switch on it.